# Do players on the winning Splatfest team get more rewards?

Tags: splatoon-2

Do you earn more rewards at the end of a Splatfest if you were on the winning team?

For example, the last Splatfest was Chicken vs Egg. Would I have earned more rewards if I had sided with the winning team Chicken?

Comment: Yes, but fortunately only a LITTLE more.  The way to get big rewards is to ensure you get to King/Queen rank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course yes, as the [Splatoon2 wikia](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Splatfest#Splatoon_2_2) states:

> Players on the winning team will earn more Super Sea Snails that those on the losing team

This rule was introduced in the first Splatoon and it has not changed. I can confirm also from personal experience.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I don't think it's explicitly stated in either Splatoon game but it's well documented [elsewhere](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Splatfest).

If two players are on opposing teams but have the same Splatfest rank - they are both Chicken / Egg Defenders for example - if Team Chicken won, the Chicken Defender gets more super sea snails.